# How to know method is JITed or interpreted

Tags: java, jvm

As I understand there is no clear rule to determine whether Java method will be JITed or interpreted while call.
So is there somehow to tell JVM that I need a certain method to be JITed. And is there a way to know for sure which method will be JITed and which not.

Comment: A method which has been compiled to native code can be un-compiled.  The system is dynamic and changes can result in compiled code being dropped.

Comment: java may not JIT the entire method either.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to know.

Comment: Nothing like answering 12 years after the question was asked - I can't speak for OP, but I need to know whether or not code is running interpreted or compiled  because it appears something is forcing my code to interpreted mode - high CPU and poor throughput where it looks like java is not actually doing much - and I would like to find out what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you don't know (from inside the JVM) and can not enforce a method being JITed or not, but using  `-XX:+PrintCompilation` JVM argument you can watch the JIT compiler doing it's work and check if a method gets JITed in that particular run of the program or not.

Answer (score 1):

> ***So is there somehow to tell JVM that I need a certain method to be JITed.***

No, which methods are "JITed" and not is not up to you, and in fact, there is no guarantee that any method will ever be JITed. I suggest you leave these decisions to the JVM.

Comment: +1: "JITting" makes no semantic difference, and is just an implementation detail for performance.  The runtime will of course try to execute all code in the fastest possible way - a developer thinking that he knows better than Hotspot, what Hotspot should do to a class is deluding himself.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Excellent comment. +1

Comment: well. erm. it is very important to know if a method gets inlined, jitted, etc when you develop a library (for instance!). Knowing how the JVM works is essential for writing performance friendly code. Not being able to inline a method but dispatch through a virtual table (and that means no cycle unrolling, no skipped boundaries checks, etc) could mean 10 times less speed...

Comment: Yep. But the point is that due to all layers of complexity, whether or not a method should be jitted, inlined, etc is in 99.9% of all cases best decided by the JVM (which has much more insight in the effects of doing so).

Comment: Actually a developer can (should be able to) have the same level 'insight', inlining is important for the very tight loops (the complexity of the code doesn't affect the inner-most loops). The JVM has issues to inline heavily morphed interfaces in larger methods (for example). Blowing inline caches (when direct inline doesn't happen) is bad too. Relying on the JVM alone to produce the best result isn't always the best case, I'd never recommend any rookie to even attempt and optimize the code to be inline-friendly but it is very important for java-based languages or just frame work developers.

Answer (score 1):

> And is there a way to know for sure
>   which method will be JITed and which
>   not.

The (Oracle) Sun JVM is called HotSpot, which means it looks at which methods are called most, thus becoming "hot", and those methods are the first to be compiled. So some methods may never be compiled. But if you know the method is called a lot, it most probably be compiled. You can set the threshold with [`-XX:CompileThreshold=10000`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#PerformanceTuning) VM options, which specifies how many invocations it takes to consider the method "hot".

I don't know any way to check whether current code is running in interpreted or compiled mode. VM crash logs show which methods in the stack trace are interpreted or compiled, maybe there's some way to get it in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to ask the jvm to compile a class, it is not guaranteed to do anything but should work on any jvm having a jit.

```
Compiler.compileClass(MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell and there is no way that it makes any difference barring bugs in HotSpot. The term 'JIT' is at least ten years out of date.